# How to pass variable from block to phtml in magento

Tags: magento, block, php

I want to pass value from block  but I am unable to get the desire results.
Something going wrong which I don't know why.
I try the code `"block type="multibanners/multibanners" name="multibanners" category_id="5" alias="multibanners"` in xml file.
To get results I used `echo $this->getCategoryId()` and `getData('category_id')`.
I search but all time the same code.
Can anyone help me whats wrong with the code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can set your variables like this:

```
<block type="multibanners/multibanners" name="multibanners" alias="multibanners">
<action method="setData"><name>category_id</name><value>5</value></action>
</block>
```

and retreive it like this:

```
$this->getCategoryId();
```

Comment: Thanks your answer working for me niki . Can you tell me how can i pass  value dynamically ?

Comment: Dynamically as in through php?

Comment: Let me explain what i try to do.I am accessing some data on categories base using my custom code .If you see the above code i can now fetch result category_id having id = 5,How can i set this value dynamic in xml and pass that value from anywhere in magento ? As there any way

Comment: You can't set it dynamically in XML (as the xml in magento is static), you need to assign it to your block object in php

Answer (score 3):

`Mage_Core_Block_Template::assign()` is made for that

Example of use in `Mage_Page_Block_Html_Breadcrumbs::_toHtml()` + direct call of `$crumbs` var in the `breadcrumbs.phtml` template file

Answer (score 1):

Or in your controller, after

```
 $this->loadLayout();
```

but before

```
 $this->renderLayout();
```

use this code:

```
$this->getLayout()->getBlock('multibanners')->setCategoryId(42);
```

Comment: Sorry Raif your code not working for me.AS i am getting result on $this->getCategoryId();

Comment: You need to provide more context, you are calling $this->getCategoryId() **from where** ? and when ? My solution will let you do  $this->getCategoryId() inside the template phtml that is rendered by the block (if it is a template block).

Comment: yes I am trying to access the code in phtml file that are rendered by my front controller. I am accessing the code in muultibanner.phtml in template folder.right ? and I add your code to the index function of my front controller.