# Pass variable from inline block to template file in magento

Tags: php, magento

I have in the magento home content

```
{{block type="catalog/navigation" template="catalog/navigation/sub_navigation.phtml"}}
```

This is calling a set of subcategorys of the given parent category ID.
Now I want to influence my `$parent_category` already from this given block. I found [How to pass variable from block to phtml in magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13194117/how-to-pass-variable-from-block-to-phtml-in-magento) but they don't show the same way of notation. 
How to integrate the `setData` action into the given block notation?
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass data like below mention method

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" name="Custom Block" category_id="68" column_count="3" product_count="3" template="catalog/navigation/sub_navigation.phtml"}}
```

after that in phtml file you can get data by below mention method

```
$this->getCategoryId();

or $this->getData('category_id');
```

Thanks.

Comment: It's working like a charm. Thanks. 
Now I'm struggeling to call it more than one time. Like: 
{{block type="catalog/navigation" category_id="5" template="/catalog/navigation/subcategorylisting-distinctive.phtml"}}


{{block type="catalog/navigation" category_id="9" template="/catalog/navigation/subcategorylisting-distinctive.phtml"}}
{{block type="catalog/navigation" category_id="38" template="/catalog/navigation/subcategorylisting-distinctive.phtml"}}

Any idea why this isn't working?

Comment: what are you getting now?

Comment: **solved** I had a function in the template which souldn't be there. Thanks!